# Automate arranging files into folders based on beginning of file name?

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, filesystem, folders

Looking to quickly arrange a whole load (talking about multiple thousands) of files into subfolders, and the files come in sets of three (left audio, right audio, video) separate files. Not experienced in terminal really but messed around in Automator before.

Example:

```
00015_A01.mxf
00015_A02.mxf
00015.mxf
00016_A01.mxf
00016_A02.mxf
00016.mxf
```

I want to automate it so that Finder looks for files with matching first characters, and puts them in a sub folder (preferably with the name of that file but I’ve managed a workaround for that.)

So the result would be:

```
[00015] (folder)
00015_A01.mxf
00015_A02.mxf
00015.mxf

[00016] (folder)
00016_A01.mxf
00016_A02.mxf
00016.mxf
```

Any ideas? I checked around on here but the answers were a bit over my head...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script will take care to construct new directories as needed and will only move new files as they appear within a given directory, into their respective subdirectories, ie. 0015, 0016, etc.

```
$ cat mover.sh
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*.mxf" -depth 1 -exec sh -c '
    file="${1/\.\//}"
    echo "$file"
    dir=${file/[_.]*mxf/}
    [ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir -p $dir
    mv $file $dir/.
' find-sh {} \;
```

With the above in a file called `mover.sh` and this file is made executable via the command `chmod +x mover.sh` we can then run it like this, `./mover.sh`.

#### Example

Here we have the following directory where some subdirectories already exist and contain their respective files.

```
$ tree .
.
├── 0015.mxf
├── 0015_A01.mxf
├── 0015_A02.mxf
├── 0016.mxf
├── 0016_A01.mxf
├── 0016_A02.mxf
├── 0017
│   ├── 0017.mxf
│   ├── 0017_A01.mxf
│   └── 0017_A02.mxf
├── 0018
│   ├── 0018.mxf
│   ├── 0018_A01.mxf
│   └── 0018_A02.mxf
└── mover.sh
```

Now we'd `cd ~/somedir` where the `*.mxf` files needing to get organized are located and run the `./mover.sh` script.

```
$ ./mover.sh
0015_A02.mxf
0015_A01.mxf
0016_A01.mxf
0016_A02.mxf
0015.mxf
0016.mxf
```

So our script has identified the above files and confirmed that their subdirectory exists and our script will move (`mv`) these *.mxf to their respective subdirectories. Here we can see the state of the directory where the *.mxf files resides after running the script:

```
$ tree
.
├── 0015
│   ├── 0015.mxf
│   ├── 0015_A01.mxf
│   └── 0015_A02.mxf
├── 0016
│   ├── 0016.mxf
│   ├── 0016_A01.mxf
│   └── 0016_A02.mxf
├── 0017
│   ├── 0017.mxf
│   ├── 0017_A01.mxf
│   └── 0017_A02.mxf
├── 0018
│   ├── 0018.mxf
│   ├── 0018_A01.mxf
│   └── 0018_A02.mxf
└── mover.sh

4 directories, 13 files
```

#### How does it work

The script makes use of a UNIX tool called `find` to produce a list of files that match the pattern `*.mxf`. This list is then iterated through and a series of commands are run on each filename found:

- `file="${1/\.\//}"` - takes each filename and removes a `./` that is prefixed to each name by `find`
- `echo "$file"` - display the results of this command to the screen
- `dir=${file/[_.]*mxf/}` - remove any trailing characters that match the patterns `_*.mxf` or `*.mxf`
- `[ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir -p $dir` - check if the directory the files goes into exists, if it doesn't make it
- `mv $file $dir/.` - move this file into the corresponding directory

#### Running this periodically

One idea here would be to setup a cronjob that runs periodically on macOS to run this script. You can read more about how to accomplish this here in this tutorial titled: [Schedule jobs with crontab on Mac OS X](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html).

The basic steps here are as follows:

- Create a crontab entry

  ```
  $ env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
  ```
- Add a entry specifying what script to run and when (every 5 mins)

  ```
  0/5 * * * *  cd ~/my/mxf/folder && ./mover.sh
  ```
- Confirm your changes

  ```
  $ crontab -l
  ```

Comment: NOTE: The `tree` utility does not exist in a default install of macOS!

Comment: Awesome.  I see you are -exec an immediate command.  What is "find-sh" about?

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! Blown away but the rapid and in depth help in this community. You all have saved me multiple days of work with your answers. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3439894 - good point, `tree` is available via `brew install tree` if you have `brew` available.

Comment: @historystamp - you can read a bit about the methods around `find` on the U&L site - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93324/how-does-this-find-command-using-find-exec-sh-c-sh-work. Basically the `find-sh` is a noop place holder to the `$0` argument, since I'm using `$@` inside, so we use `find-sh` as a nonce to make things easier to read.

Comment: @historystamp - UNIX/Linux ppl like to be clever 8-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in {10..99}
do
    mkdir 000$i
    mv 000$i* 000$i
done

for i in {100..999}
do
    mkdir 00$i
    mv 00$i* 00$i
done

for i in {1000..9999}
do
    mkdir 0$i
    mv 0$i* 0$i
done
```

This bash script should work for 10-9999 directories.

Comment: That does not take much understanding - short & sweet...

Comment: Or go the full way by running `mkdir 000{10..99}` first, followed by a loop to move the files :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So how would I set this to run on a batch of files in the finder? Do I navigate to the containing folder in finder then use this command? Is there a way to use this as an action in Automator? Thank you again.

Comment: you need to use the command line via the Terminal app. its located in the Applications/Utilities folder. Double click on the terminal app. Go to the proper folder, and just run the script.  edit a file named yourscript.sh, type in the script, and run it. To run it type chmod +x yourscript.sh. Then just type ./yourscript.sh at the prompt.

Comment: i've editted my answer to help...

Comment: Given that AskDifferent caters to a broader audience than other SE sites, such as stackoverflow, I would recommend to provide more explanation as to how this answer can be effectively used.

Comment: Super!  little bit about Unix. https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-11071

Comment: I suggest using nano in the terminal.  nano yourscript.sh  Now, you copy and paste the above code into the terminal hence nano  control + x; y for yes; press return; etc.

Comment: or you can use bbedit or textwrangler

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help, this has saved me a massive amount of headache! What a great community!

Answer (score 0):

As of Mac OS 10.14.4 I have not been able to find such function but you can hold command (windows key if using a windows keyboard) then click with two fingers on trackpad or left click and say "New Folder with Selection".

Comment: Thanks for your input, I’ve been using this method for now, but going through thousands of files three at a time is taking a very long time... appreciate the reply though!